# Is this AGAL output correct?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, stage3d, agal

I am trying to convert this shaders:

```
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec2 pos;
            attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

            varying vec4 vColor;

            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
                vColor = aVertexColor;
            }

        </script>
```

and

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 vColor;

        void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }

        </script>
```

Having as a result (**Does this output looks good to you? or I am missing something**):

```
mov vt0.zw, vc0.xyyy
mov vt0.x, va0.x
mov vt0.y, va0.y
mov op, vt0
mov v0, va1
```

and

```
mov oc, v0
```

But I am not able to display anything, if I change the AGAL vertex shader for something much simple works:

```
mov op, va0n
mov v0, va1n
```

I add the constants when I convert the GLSL to AGAL via:

```
var constval:Array;
                for (var constant:String in result.consts) {
                    trace(constant, result.consts[constant]);
                    constval = result.consts[constant];
                    context.setProgramConstantsFromVector( type, int(constant.slice(2)), Vector.<Number>([constval[0], constval[1], constval[2], constval[3]]) )    
                }
```

And I prepare all the buffers like this:

```
    var vertices:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([
        -0.3,-0.3,0, 1, 0, 0, // x, y, z, r, g, b
        -0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 1]);


    const dataPerVertex:int = 6;
    vertexbuffer = context.createVertexBuffer(vertices.length/dataPerVertex, dataPerVertex);
    vertexbuffer.uploadFromVector(vertices, 0, vertices.length/dataPerVertex );         

    var indices:Vector.<uint> = Vector.<uint>([0, 1, 2]);
    indexbuffer = context.createIndexBuffer(3);         
    indexbuffer.uploadFromVector (indices, 0, 3);       

    context.setVertexBufferAt (0, vertexbuffer, 0, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3); //Defines shader input va0 as the position data
    context.setVertexBufferAt(1, vertexbuffer, 3, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3);//Defines shader input va1 as the position data
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that at least this line is wrong: "mov vt0.zw, vc0.xyyy". As far as I know, both src and dst must have the same type, but here src is float4 and dst is float2. What are you attempting to do in this line?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of inconsistencies I can see:

1. Where are you setting the values in constval?  Assign Vector.([constval[0], constval[1], constval[2], constval[3]]) to a variable and inspect it in the debugger.
2. Do the array values have x=0.0 and y=1.0?
3. Are you setting your constants just before you set your vertex buffers? It's possible your constants could get overwritten by other render code.
4. Your vertex buffer is a FLOAT_3 format for both position and colour but your vertex shader asks for an vec2 attribute for position and a vec4 for the colour.

It's more likely that the constants are the problem.  You can test if your constants are to blame by hardcoding them in your position vector, like so:

1. Hard code the constants for 0.0 and 1.0

   ```
   var vertices:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([
       -0.3,-0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0, 0, // x, y, z=0.0, w=1.0, r, g, b
       -0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0, 1, 0,
       0.3, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 1]);
   ```
2. Change the size of your vertex data to match

   ```
   const dataPerVertex:int = 7;
   ```
3. Change your buffer settings to reflect the new sizes and offsets

   ```
   context.setVertexBufferAt (0, vertexbuffer, 0, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_4); //Defines shader input va0 as the position data
   context.setVertexBufferAt(1, vertexbuffer, 4, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3);//Defines shader input va1 as the position data
   ```
4. Now change your script here:

   ```
   attribute vec4 pos;
   ```
5. And here:

   ```
   gl_Position = pos;
   ```

If your problems go away, it would suggest that you aren't sending the right constants.  Revert to your old code and make sure you're uploading your constants properly.